# Managing tag_id using osm2pgrouting

Tags: osm2pgrouting

After import highway with osm2pgrouting, i'd like to filter with tags. My problem is that i only have an attribute "tag_id" which contains number not literal values.

Where can I find a table that associates tag_id(number) with tag(character) ?

Answer (score 0):

the response is pretty simple.
osm2pgrouting creates a table name "configuration" which contains the information.